# How to define map extents based on a feature's geometry?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, extents

There is a polygon geometry in my QGIS project which represents the extents of my map. Does anybody know how to use the data defined override to get the X/Y min and X/Y max coordinates of the polygon in the print composer?

[image]

Unfortunately this isn't working:

```
xmin(attribute(getFeature('layername', 'gid', 1), 'geom'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometry can be accessed directly rather than through the attributes:

```
x_min(geometry(getFeature('airports', 'cat', 1)))
```

Comment: Yeah, works fine using 'xmin' instead of 'x_min'!