# Creating zoomed in portion of map in print composer

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer

I posted a question yesterday about troubles I was having with labeling (which are still plaguing me), but it hit me today that it would probably be easier for me to just create zoomed in sections of my map to be able to show all of the labels properly (they are very close point locations). The problem is that I have no idea how to do this! I know that I can add another map in a smaller window and zoom from there, but I'm not sure how to get the boxed area perfectly matched up (if that makes sense).

Can anyone help?

[image: I have included an image of what I'm talking about here.]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you go to your print composer, you add a new map as you normally would (let´s say it is `Map 1`). Leave enough space for your zoomed in portion to be displayed.

Add a new smaller, map in the area where you want your zoomed in portion to be displayed (let´s say it is `Map 2`). Within this window, zoom to whatever area you want.

In the "Item Properties" tab of `Map 1`, scroll down to "Overview" and hit the green + symbol.

[image]
[image]

Set the map frame to `Map 1` (this should be the full extent base map you're working with).

Set the map frame to `Map 2` (this should be the zoomed in portion).

Set the symbology for your new overview in `Map 1`.

[image]

(Note: I was fiddling with it for a bit before I realized that the border style was set to "no pen" instead of solid line, which is what I wanted. Just pay attention to the details and you should be fine!)

Finnaly, I have added some lines manually and this is the results:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just create a polygon feature that represents the frame of your zoomed in section and use data defined override for the extents in the print composer.

```
xmin(geometry(getFeature('frame', 'gid', 1)))
ymin(geometry(getFeature('frame', 'gid', 1)))
xmax(geometry(getFeature('frame', 'gid', 1)))
ymax(geometry(getFeature('frame', 'gid', 1)))
```

[How to define map extents based on a feature's geometry?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150042/how-to-define-map-extents-based-on-a-features-geometry)